# Powershell copy $source memberof to destination without copying $destination's existing membership and additional filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to copy a user's group membership with some exceptions. I would like to copy source's groups to destination unless the destination user is already a member. There are some groups that I do not want to copy on that of that.

```
$copyfrom = Read-Host "Enter Username of User Origin" 
$copyto = Read-Host "Enter Username of User Destination"
$badstring = 'bad'
Get-ADUser $copyfrom -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Where-Object { -not $_.Substring(3).StartsWith($badstring)} | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $copyto
```

I am missing the part where the script skips the group that a user is already a member of.

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below should do ti:

```
$copyfrom  = Read-Host "Enter Username of User Origin" 
$copyto    = Read-Host "Enter Username of User Destination"
$badstring = 'bad'

# get the ADUser object for the source user
$srcUser  = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$copyfrom'" -Properties MemberOf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
if (!$srcUser) {
    Write-Warning "User $copyfrom not found"
    exit
}

# get the ADUser object for the destination user
$destUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$copyto'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$destUser) {
    Write-Warning "User $copyto not found"
    exit
}

$srcUser | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | 
    Where-Object { -not $_.Substring(3).StartsWith($badstring)} |
    # loop through the groups and add the user if not already a member
    ForEach-Object {
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
        if ($members -notcontains $destUser.SamAccountName) {
            $_ | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $destUser.DistinguishedName
        }
    }
```